# Linha 36: Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null

Tags: javascript, html, dom

Opa, tudo bom?
Eu estou fazendo um projeto de vários teste do firebase.
Pórem ele está dando o seguinte erro:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'addEventListener' of null
```

Esse erro está sendo dado na linha 36 do meu código javascript:

```
var firebaseConfig = {
  apiKey: "0",
  authDomain: "0",
  databaseURL: "0",
  projectId: "0",
  storageBucket: "0",
  messagingSenderId: "0",
  appId: "0",
  measurementId: "0"
};
// Initialize Firebase
firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

var firestore = firebase.firestore();
const outputHeader = document.querySelector("#numeroOutput");
const inputTextFieldNome = document.querySelector("#nome");
const inputTextFieldIdade = document.querySelector("#idade");
const saveButton = document.querySelector("#mandar");

saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
  const nome = inputTextFieldNome.value;
  const idade = inputTextFieldIdade.value;
  console.log("Estamos dalvando o seu numero");
  const docRef = firestore.collection("usuarios/").doc(nome);
  docRef.set({
    Idade: idade
  }).then(function () {
    console.log("Salvo com sucesso!");
  }).catch(function (error) {
    console.log("Peguei um erro", error);
  });
});

var uploader = document.querySelector("#uploader");
var fileButton = document.querySelector("#fileButton");
fileButton.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  //Get File
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  //Storage Reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("txts/" + file.name);
  //Upload File
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
  //Update Progress Bar
  task.on("state_changed",
    function progress(snapshot) {
        var percentage =  snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
        uploader.value = percentage;
    },
    function error(err) {

    },
    function complete() {

    });
});
```

O firebaseConfig está zerado porque eu coloquei assim pra poder postar.
E o meu código Html está da seguinte maneira:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <title>Firebase</title>

    <style media="screen">
        body{
            display: flex;
            min-height: 100vh;
            width: 100%;
            padding: 0;
            margin: 0;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            flex-direction: column;
        }
        #uploader{
            -webkit-appearance: none;
            appearance: none;
            width: 50%;
            margin-bottom: 10px;
        }
    </style>


    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.4/firebase-app.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.4/firebase-firestore.js"></script>
    <script src="https://www.gstatic.com/firebasejs/7.15.4/firebase-storage.js"></script>
</head>
</head>

<body>

    <h1 id="numeroOutput">Firebase</h1>
    <h2>Firestore</h2>
    Nome : <input type="textfield" id="nome"><br>
    Idade : <input type="textfield" id="idade"><br>
    <button id="mandar">Enviar!</button>
    <script src="./app.js"></script>

    <br>

    <h2>Storage</h2>
    <progress value="0" max="100" id="uploader">0%</progress><br>
    <input type="file" value="upload" id="fileButton" />
</body>

</html>
```

Me ajudem por favor!

Comment: Pela mensagem de erro dá para deduzir que a variável `fileButton` está como o valor `null`. Porém o código para inicia-la está correto, é possível que o seu JavaScript esteja rodando antes do DOM ser carregado, por isso ele não encontra está encontrando o elemento `#fileButton`. Tente colocar seu código dentro de uma função e então invocar essa função no evento `onload` da sua página, que é disparado quando o DOM é carregado por completo.

Comment: Importante você [edit] sua pergunta e explicar de maneira objetiva e pontual a dificuldade encontrada, acompanhada de um [mcve] do problema e tentativa de solução. Para aproveitar melhor o site, entender e evitar fechamentos e negativações vale a pena ler o [Guia de sobrevivência do Stack Overflow em Português](https://pt.meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8045/70).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Faça como o user140828 disse: seu script está sendo executado antes do DOM ser carregado.
É só colocar seu script dentro de `window.onload` que garante que o código será executado depois do DOM ser carregado:

```js
window.onload = function(){
  var firebaseConfig = {
    apiKey: "0",
    authDomain: "0",
    databaseURL: "0",
    projectId: "0",
    storageBucket: "0",
    messagingSenderId: "0",
    appId: "0",
    measurementId: "0"
  };
  // Initialize Firebase
  firebase.initializeApp(firebaseConfig);

  var firestore = firebase.firestore();
  const outputHeader = document.querySelector("#numeroOutput");
  const inputTextFieldNome = document.querySelector("#nome");
  const inputTextFieldIdade = document.querySelector("#idade");
  const saveButton = document.querySelector("#mandar");

  saveButton.addEventListener("click", function () {
    const nome = inputTextFieldNome.value;
    const idade = inputTextFieldIdade.value;
    console.log("Estamos dalvando o seu numero");
    const docRef = firestore.collection("usuarios/").doc(nome);
    docRef.set({
      Idade: idade
    }).then(function () {
      console.log("Salvo com sucesso!");
    }).catch(function (error) {
      console.log("Peguei um erro", error);
    });
  });

  var uploader = document.querySelector("#uploader");
  var fileButton = document.querySelector("#fileButton");
  fileButton.addEventListener("change", function (e) {
  //Get File
  var file = e.target.files[0];
  //Storage Reference
  var storageRef = firebase.storage().ref("txts/" + file.name);
  //Upload File
  var task = storageRef.put(file);
  //Update Progress Bar
  task.on("state_changed",
  function progress(snapshot) {
    var percentage =  snapshot.bytesTransferred / snapshot.totalBytes * 100;
      uploader.value = percentage;
    },
    function error(err) {
    },
    function complete() {
    });
  });
}
```